# Vowel indices: Python error "'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not int"

Tags: python, string, for-loop

I'm a beginner when it's about Python, and I do not quite understand the following:

I try to print the indices of all the vowels that are in the string:

```
string = "And now for something completely different"
vowel = "aeiouAEIOU"

for i in range(0, len(string)):
    if i in vowel:  
        print(string[i])
```

So, the output should be something like this, I think:

```
[0, 5, 9, 13, 15, 18, 23, 27, 29, 34, 37, 39]
```

Then I get this error:

```
"'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not int"
```

I think I do understand that both variables I try to compare should be strings, but I do not see how 'i' is not a string because it does go by every letter of 'string'.

How do I get rid of this error? Maybe I did more wrong, and that is why this code is not working.

I tried to look at similar questions, but the answers did not fit my question entirely and therefore I still haven't figured it out.

Comment: `i` is the **index**, not the character. Try `for char in string: if char in vowel:`. You literally do the right thing on the next line, not sure why this has surprised you.

Comment: To get both the index and the content while iterating, you can use something like `[ind for ind, ch in enumerate(string) if ch in vowel]`.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen they don’t actually need the index, they only use it to get the character (but not for `in`, for some reason).

Comment: @jonrsharpe I wasn't sure because of their "output" being `[0, 5, 9, 13, 15, 18, 23, 27, 29, 34, 37, 39]` and the title being "vowel indices". I'll leave it to OP to decide what it is they want before doing it I guess : )

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen oh maybe, it’s unclear why they expected `string[i]` to be the index in that case.

Comment: It's amazing how many pivoted answers here use range(len(string)) as opposed to just iterating the string...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to check if `i`, which is an integer, is included in the string `vowel`.

```
string = "And now for something completely different"
vowel = "aeiouAEIOU"

for i in range(0, len(string)):
    if string[i] in vowel:  
        print(string[i])
```

By doing this you will print each character in the string that fulfill the inclusion condition.

Answer (score 5):

> but I do not see how 'i' is not a string because it does go by every letter of 'string'.

Nope, here `i` is an integer ranging from 0 to `len(string) - 1`. Which you could have seen just by `print`ing `i` in your loop...

If you want to iterate on `string` letters, it's spelled:

```
for char in string:
    print char
```

Now here you want both the index (for the output) and the letter (for lookup), so you should use `enumerate(sequence)` which yields an `(index, item)` tuple for each item in `sequence`:

```
for index, char in enumerate(string):
    if char in vowel:
        print index
```

Also you could speed up the lookup by making `vowels` a `set`:

```
vowels = set("aeiouAEIOU")
```

this doesn't change the rest of the code, but lookup will be O(1) instead of O(N)

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate explanation! It is appreciated. I am only afraid that the enumerate() is still too advanced for me. I am still at the start of a beginners course of Python. But thanks! I will store this information, because there are still interesting tips in your answers.

Comment: `enumerate()` is in now way "advanced" - as you can see it's dead easy to use - and it's _the_ pythonic way to iterate on both items and indexes of a sequence. But you first have to understand python's `for` loops indeed ;)

Answer (score 3):

To print the indices use this.

```
string = "And now for something completely different"
vowel = "aeiouAEIOU"

for i in range(0, len(string)):
    if string[i] in vowel:  
       print(i)
```

i is an integer index not a character.. `string[i]` the ith character in a string. the above code prints every vowel index in a string.

Answer (score 2):

Bruno answer is really good, and explain clearly the problem. Just to complete you can also use something call list comprehension to do what you want :

```
>>> string = "And now for something completely different"
>>> vowel = "aeiouAEIOU"
>>> result=[i for i in range(len(string)) if string[i] in vowel]
>>> result
[0, 5, 9, 13, 15, 18, 23, 27, 29, 34, 37, 39]
```